How to phrase “Sing in your chains like the sea”
I want to use the phrase “Canta in catenis tuis sicut mare” with an intended meaning of “Sing in your chains like the sea”. It is inspired by a line from Dylan Thomas’ Fern Hill.  The actual and complete line is actually, “Time held me, green and dying, though I sang in my chains like the sea”.  The poem is about holding on to, being amazed by, and celebrating life, while constantly in the crosshairs of the passage of time. My summary is very incomplete, but my goal is to provide the meaning of the phrase to make sure the translation that I have arrived at is accurate. Thank you!
